# ¿como puedo ingresar datos a dos tablas relacionadas en php, desde un solo formulario?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo dos tablas una que se llama "pregunta" y la otra usuarios.
TABLA PREGUNTA con sus campos que son (pregunta, repuesta).

TABLA USUARIOS con sus campos (nombre, apellido, correo,)

donde el id de la tabla usuarios esta relaciona con el "campo usuario" de la tabla pregunta.

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];

$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];

$correo = $_POST["correo"];

$clave = $_POST["clave"];

$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];

$pregunta = $_POST["pregunta"];

$repuesta = $_POST["respuesta"];



    $insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellido, correo, clave, telefono, pregunta, repuesta)
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$clave', '$telefono', '$pregunta', '$repuesta')";

   $insertar = "INSERT INTO pregunta(pregunta, repuesta)
    VALUES ('$pregunta', '$repuesta')";
```

Comment: Necesitamos mas detalles, por ejemplo si usas mysqli o PDO así como tu consulta completa por favor

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema o el error?

Answer (score 3):

el "ID" de usuario de la tabla "usuarios" seguramente lo tienes como `AUTO_INCREMENT`, ¿el "campo usuario" de la tabla preguntas como lo tienes definido?

La forma **LARGA** de hacerlo (Según lo que te logro entender) sería:

1-. insertar los datos en la table `Usuario` de la forma que lo tienes escrito(para que se te genera la "`ID`" de usuario).

2-. Realizar un `select`,para recuperar esa "`iD`" de usuario

3-. realizar el `insert` en la tabla preguntas, y pasando el "`ID`" de usuario, esto para que ambas tablas te queden relacionadas en base al "`ID`"
ej:

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO pregunta(pregunta, repuesta,usuario)
             VALUES ('$pregunta', '$repuesta','$id_Usuario')";
```